# How to add button to any datagridview column's last cell

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I want to add button in last cell of any columns. This is not working. How can I do for this?

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    DataGridViewButtonCell button = (row.Cells["1"] as DataGridViewButtonCell);
}
```

EDIT: I don't want to add column. I want to add these button on any columns' last cell, not row's.

[image]

Comment: add a `DataGridViewButtonColumn`, you can also do this in designer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to create a `DataGridViewButtonCell` for each Column you want to adorn:

```
DataGridViewButtonCell cell_1 = new DataGridViewButtonCell();
```

Then you can replace the original `Cells` with the `DataGridViewButtonCells`:

```
dataGridView1[oneOfYourButtonColumnIndices , buttonRowIndex] = cell_1;
```

Note that you need to create **seperate** `Cells` for each Button! Each can only be added once!

You can style the Cell as you like:

```
cell_1.Value = "Conquer";
cell_1.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
```

Hoever you **can't** register any `events` with it as the type `DataGridViewCell` is not a `Control` and does not implement an event model.

Instead all events must be handled in the `DataGridView`. Here is an example:

```
List<int> YourButtonColumnIndices = new List<int> {3,5,7};

private void DGV_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewCell cell = DGV[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex];

    // check if we have hit a button cell..
    if (YourButtonColumnIndices.Contains(e.ColumnIndex) && cell is DataGridViewButtonCell )
    {
        Console.WriteLine(cell.Value.ToString());
        // do things that depend on the button:
        // if (cell.Value == "Conquer")  doConquer(..);
        // else (cell.Value == "Command")  doCommand(..);
        // ..
    }
}
```

You can see that I can access the cell's Value just like normal. It is also displayed as the Button's Text.

Note that all Cells have a `Tag` property and you could store anything you like in there, including a delegate!

Also note that in your model the buttons' row may well change when you insert or delete rows. Therefore you should take care to either refer to the `buttonRowIndex` only when you add the buttons or keep it up to date. I didn't event check for it in the `Click` event as the column index plus the cell type should be enough. If they are not, you can also check on the values..

Of course you can code the `doCommand` methods as you like, adding parameters as needed..

Btw: Regular buttons are always `Silver` or whatever your system has for buttons in its color scheme. But you can make them `FlatStyle` buttons and voila, the `Cell's Backcolor` (and/or `Forecolor`) will be used:

```
 cell_1.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
 cell_1.Style.BackColor = Color.LightSkyBlue;
```

[image]

If you have more than two or three such buttons you may want to create a `Dictionary` to manage them, maybe like this:

```
Dictionary<int, string> buttonList = new Dictionary<int, string>();
buttonList.Add(3, "Save Operator");
buttonList.Add(5, "Save An.1");
buttonList.Add(7, "Save An.2");
```

and use it to create them:

```
foreach(int i in buttonList.Keys)
  {
     DataGridViewButtonCell cell= new DataGridViewButtonCell();
     cell.Value = buttonList[i];
     cell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
     dataGridView1[i, buttonRowIndex] = cell;
  }
```

and to check for them in the `CellClick`:

```
if (buttonList.Keys.Contains(e.ColumnIndex) && cell is DataGridViewButtonCell )
{  
  if (e.ColumnIndex] == 3) doStuff3()
  else if (e.ColumnIndex] == 5) doStuff5()
  //..
```

Comment: Do they contain click event? Is it possible to reach it's column values?

Comment: I'll be waiting. Thanks.

Comment: This is working fine. The column count will be apperant in runtime (Maybe 14, maybe 30). How can I define these specific button names?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'names':  "Conquer" or 'cell_1' ? - The formar are just  strings; you set them as values & they show up as button texts. If you need to check on them it would be a good idea to store them in one place so you need to change them only there; maybe a Dictionary<int colindex, string name>. - For the latter you can either declare them locally as above. Then they are lost when the script goes out of scope. Or you declare eg class variables, which you can refer to at any time.  - Note that they still only refer to Cells __not__ to real buttons! You can't really click them..

Comment: Thanks a lot. There is a problem. When I click any buttons, their tags doesn't appear. They seems valueless. How could be this?

Comment: Well, let's see. Have you used the debugger? Do you enter the CellClick event and the if clause? Also: What exactly do you mean by 'the Tags not appearing'?? What do you expect? What have you coded for it to happen? Did you write some doSomeCommand methods?

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

As question is now updated and the requirement is to add button to the `cell` not the button column entirely.

You can use [`DataGridViewButtonCell`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewbuttoncell(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var button = new DataGridViewButtonCell();
```

in case, if you need a button column below code will help.

[`DataGridViewButtonColumn`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewButtonColumn(v=vs.110).aspx) is what you need.

```
DataGridViewButtonColumn button = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
    button.Name = "WhatEver";
    button.Text = "ClickMe";

dataGridView1.Columns.Add(button);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could employ a template field instead of a bound field. This would enable you to place a footer inside the field.

```
<asp:TemplateField>
       <ItemTemplate>
             <asp:Button ID="btnEdit" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' />
       </ItemTemplate>
       <FooterTemplate>
         <asp:Button ID="btnNew" CommandName="New" Text="New" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' />
       </FooterTemplate>                 
</asp:TemplateField>
```

And if I remember correctly, this is then handled in the rowcommand event (therefore the command name and arguement).